# Que técnicas existem para homologação de sistemas?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, requisitos

Que técnica posso usar para homologar software?

Existe algum tipo de formulário, padrão, técnica ou procedimento para validarmos se um sistema atende aos requisitos?

Existe algum padrão de documento para formalizar essa homologação?

Comment: Editei para a pergunta ficar respondível dentro das regras. Se achar que ficou ruim ,pode reverter, mas aí não me responsabilizo se ela for fechada.

Comment: @bigown ainda sim, acho a pergunta bastante ampla, estudei este tema quase um semestre inteiro e ainda faltou muita coisa a ser ensinada.

Comment: @diegofm depende, a pergunta não pede detalhes, acho que pode ser respondida em linhas gerais. Aí se ele achar que alguma merece aprofundamento faz uma perguntas mais específica.

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição pessoal. Pode ser respondida em linhas gerais sim e se tiverem algum livro/artigo para indicar eu agradeço. Pode ser em inglês mesmo.

Comment: Desculpe, votei para fechar pois é amplo demais. Acho que poderia ter um foco específico pois "homologação" tem diversos tipos. Exemplo, tem a homologação do Estado (Governo), tem a homologação privada (cada empresa adota ou cria um padrão), etc. Até mesmo um autônomo pode adotar ou criar um padrão de homologação. Por fim, da forma como está a pergunta é inviável responder. Terá respostas dispersas pois não tem um foco, daí vem  interpretação "ampla demais".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Homologação*, no sentido vulgar usado nas empresas, significa apenas obter uma confirmação do usuário, um "aceite", de que o software atende ao que ele precisa.

Não existe regra ou processo padrão aqui, embora provavelmente você encontre alguns modelos por aí.

Existem alguns frameworks de processos como RUP ou ITIL que falam alguma coisa sobre homologação, às vezes usando termos como testes de aceitação ou ainda outros. Veja [este artigo](https://www.profissionaisti.com.br/2010/07/a-itil-e-o-ambiente-de-aceite-ou-homologacao/), por exemplo.

No entanto, embora eles sugiram boas práticas, eles não prescrevem todas as ações e práticas, cabe a você compreender o que o método propõe e aplicar isso de acordo com suas necessidades.

Para realizar testes de homologação, você segue princípios gerais de testes de sistema, mas não existe uma regra específica e varia dependendo do tipo de sistema.

Para documentar você usa a ferramenta que tiver à mão. Pode ser um sistema interno como Bugzilla ou JIRA, um documento de texto ou mesmo uma planilha. Documentos relacionados a testes podem também aparecer em formato de checklists, exigindo que você verifique determinados itens especificamente.

Se você comprar uma consultoria para algum processo eles fornecerão modelos e ajudarão a personalizar de acordo com suas necessidades.

Entretanto, fazendo um contraponto com a outra resposta, é muito importante você diferenciar aspectos legais dos aspectos pragmáticos que envolvem a satisfação do cliente, em relação ao problema que envolve entregar algo que pode conter defeitos ocultos.

Sobre aspectos legais, procure um advogado especializado, peça e-mails, assinaturas, etc.

Agora, pense do outro lado. Quando você exige que o cliente assine uma declaração de que o sistema "funciona", na prática, você está se eximindo da responsabilidade de testar ele adequadamente e prover garantia. Qual o objetivo de jogar na cara do cliente um documento assinado quando ele encontra erros óbvios no sistema?

O primeiro passo para chegar a um processo razoável de homologação é ter os requisitos e objetivos do sistema bem claros.

A segunda coisa é estabelecer uma comunicação com o cliente que permita certa flexibilidade na mudança de requisitos dentro do mesmo orçamento e deixar claro o custo para alterações maiores.

Além disso, é importante diferenciar a não adequação aos requisitos (por exemplo, usar juros simples quando o requisito diz que deveria ser composto) de erros de implementação (por exemplo, o cálculo de juros retorna valores incorretos em certos casos).

A garantia do sistema em geral se aplica aos erros apenas e você deve deixar isto claro.

A homologação, do ponto de vista do cliente, deve ser uma verificação geral de que o sistema está fazendo o que ele realmente pediu, mas não é um atestado de que não existem erros.

Quem escreve o software é o principal responsável por realizar os testes e também treinar os usuários e demonstrar o sistema para eles. O cliente não é o especialista.

Pense num automóvel. Já pensou se o fabricante pedisse para você assinar um documento de que não há nenhum problema no veículo após um *test drive*? Talvez você argumente que um carro é um item caro. Bem, um software que não vale o custo de sua própria qualidade e manutenção talvez não devesse nem ter sido feito.

Comment: Obrigado pelo resposta. Acho que você entendeu errado. Não quero um documento assinado pelo cliente informando que o sistema funciona. Quero informações sobre técnicas que ajudem a documentar os problemas encontrados na homologação.

Comment: @MarcoAntonioQuintal Essa parte sobre assinatura é um contraposto com a outra resposta. A parte que responde à sua pergunta é a do começo: não existe um processo padrão,  embora você encontre alguns modelos por aí.

Comment: Obrigado pelas informações.

Comment: @MarcoAntonioQuintal Eu atualizei a resposta para esclarecer alguns pontos melhores. Dá uma lida de novo no começo. Do meio para o fim não alterei nada.

Answer (score 2):

Olha, creio que sua pergunta seja para fins didáticos, e eu queria aplicar todo o conhecimento que a faculdade me deu pra responder com gosto essa pergunta. Mas sinceramente, acho que mais vale uma resposta estapafúrdia compartilhando algumas experiencias, do que um emanado de texto teórico sobre homologação de sistema, documentação, que nem faz tanto sentido assim vendo na prática. Espero uma resposta melhor a sua pergunta, mas eu queria mesmo ver mais experiencias dos demais usuários compartilhadas aqui também.

**Mensagens de texto, ligação e e-mail não vale como homologação... é óbvio!**

O primeiro sistema que eu fiz (na época eu era rebelde e não dava ouvidos ao que eu via na faculdade), foi um sistema comercial adaptado a uma empresa pequena, decidi não fazer documentação de homologação. Logo, trabalhei por uns par de meses (após a entrega efetiva do sistema sem homologação), fazendo pequenas adaptações, por que como a rotatividade de funcionários na empresa era grande, então cada um novo que entrada, havia "sugestões" para dar no sistema, eu muito atencioso atendia elas, fazia questão de pedir a todos que mandassem as melhorias e as vezes correções por e-mail, pois eu pensava "terei tudo isso no e-mail, vou poder cobrar depois" e, bom, se eu pensava que receber um e-mail dizendo *"querido, o **controle funciona**, mas dá para por um botão a mais ali no cantinho?"* ou *"**tá funcionando**, mas eu queria que você abrisse uma exceção, pode ser"*, *"moço da informática, tá lindo isso, uma maravilha, **funciona** até quando meu computador tá desligado, vem aqui toma um café"* e eu cético que iria imprimir todos esses e-mails e comprovar que o sistema está operacional (logo isso na minha cabeça queria dizer que já estava homologado) e ainda cobrar pelos serviço extra. Pois bem, perdi de ganhar pelo meu serviço nesses oito meses de *"correção da melhoria"* ali, *"correção da correção de uma abertura de exceção aqui"*, aí aprendi que isso não seria uma boa forma de homologação, pois na cabeça do dono da empresa, tudo que eu estava fazendo após a entrega do sistema, era correção ou melhoria de algo já encomendado por eles.

**Homologar tudo em formulário não resolve 100% e dá caca**

No segundo sistema, aprendi a lição (que citei acima e já não estava mais rebelde na faculdade, então eu acolhi os ensinamentos) e eu comecei a fazer formulários (em papel mesmo) ao longo do desenvolvimento do sistema. O formulário era simples, era um campo em torno de **"testou e tem certeza que está funcionando a funcionalidade xzy: (  ) sim (  ) não"** refletindo o escopo inicial do projeto e assim por diante, bem descrito funcionalidade por funcionalidade. Bom, chegou um ponto que eu tava fazendo homologação em cima de formulário de homologação de uma outra homologação já feita uma ou mais vezes por mim mesmo ou pelos demais membros da equipe. Logo percebi, que a analise que eu e minha equipe fizemos alguns meses, não teve peso na hora da homologação, por que, o **dono da empresa** descrevendo uma funcionalidade é uma coisa, usuário descrevendo e pedindo uma **funcionalidade** é outra coisa, usuário **testando/usando** parece que ele vai pra outra dimensão que é inversa a dimensão que o dono da empresa estava quando descreveu/solicitou as funcionalidades.

**Agora eu homologo sistema fazendo com que o usuário faça uma declaração escrita, com testemunhas e com reconhecimento de firma** (inclusive eu queria ter videos, fotos, gravações de áudio e leitura biométrica nesse instante rsrs)

Pra começar, é sério. Cada etapa do desenvolvimento, eu levo o usuário a exaustão obrigando a completar o processo, **declarando para os devidos fins...** que realizou o teste do sistema, em determinada data, em determinado lugar, com a presença de testemunhas, certificando que a funcionalidade é como o esperado, que não houveram erros durante o processo, e que melhorias e sugestões devem ser enviadas após a entrega do sistema ser efetivada (como deve e sempre deverá ser). Faço isso não por que eu quero, mas é por que eu não quero que a empresa que eu trabalho, perca dinheiro e tão pouco que o cliente que eu atenda fique insatisfeito. Pessoalmente, eu preferiria fazer tudo que o usuário pede, recebendo ou não, é um prazer fazer as coisas acontecerem, mas isso é um desgosto para empresa que paga meu salário.

**Mas, uma homologação de fato é assim e tem que ser assim sempre**

*Querido*, deixa todo o sistema funcionando, só! Sai da sala, vai toma um café saltitando pela empresa, faça um formulário lindão, enche um monte de linguiça nele, um não, milhares... No final do processo de homologação, tira uma foto com o V da vitória de você e quem tava nesse processo, posta no face, thumblr, twitter com as *hashtags* #homologacaoTop #funfouTudo #semMaisHelloWorld, sai da sala, passa pelo corredor fazendo *highfive* com tudo mundo, dança com a tia da limpeza, abre um sorriso daqueles, o cliente vai ver o seu semblante de felicidade e você vai contagiar todo mundo, e aquela harmonia.... ah aquela harmonia, aquela felicidade que vai tomar conta do departamento, aquela sim é uma baita de uma homologação bem feita, o processo no final das contas que vale é esse !

Brincadeiras a parte, desejo boa sorte quando chegar nesse ponto.